# What is "reverse certification"

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, words, hechsher-certification

I got this in a daily halacha email but not sure what Reverse Certification means, I figure someone here does

> Reverse Certification
>
> It is permitted for a mashgiach to enter a non-kosher establishment for reverse certification. Since it is a requirement for the hashgacha organization it is permitted since maris ayin is permitted in the place of a loss.

Comment: That sounds intriguing. I've also never heard of this term and can barely guess what it might mean. Have you considered asking whoever sends out the email? If you do, and you get a useful answer, please post it here!

Comment: Reverse certification can mean making sure nothing Kosher is happening, or in industrial certification, it can mean sending in a Mashgiach when non-Kosher is produced (to limit its effect on the rest of the factory). So whereas a typical company would pay for a Mashgiach when they want something certified, this arrangement keeps them certified year round they pay for a Mashgiach to watch them produce the non-Kosher.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on Footnote 3 of [Halachically Speaking](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/) Volume 5 [Issue 12](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/volume_5_issue_12.pdf) (which seems to also be the source of the text in the question):

> If Mister Jones has two restaurants, one kosher one not-kosher, and I certify the kosher one, I occasionally go into the non-kosher restaurant to make sure that nothing there claims to be certified by me.

I never would have thought of that!